# how to close .exe application on button click

Tags: c#, process

Can any one tell me how can I close .exe file on button click using c#. I've got an idea of how to run .exe file on button click using c# as follows:

```
string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
process.Start();
```

But can anyone tell me how to close .exe application on button click in c#?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to call [`CloseMainWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) on the `Process`. This is analogous to clicking on the close button of the window, so it may not actually close the application.

For example, if the user edited some text in the window, but didn't save it, this will show the “Do you want to save your changes?” dialog.

If you want to really close the application, no matter what, you can use [`Kill()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx). This may cause loss of data (the edits to the file won't be saved), but that may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should write under your button click something like this:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

This will close your current window, if its `MDI child window`. Else it will close the application (assuming you got only one window open).

Comment: I think the query was about closing a process and not about closing an MDI Window.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Process.Kill();
```

Or to kill all instances of notepad you could do:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")) {
   process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: I don't think the question is how to kill all notepads on the computer.

Comment: i do think it pretty much tells OP how to use it in a scenario.

Comment: @nawfal, it does now, but when I wrote my comment, this answer was just the second piece of code with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you asking for [Process.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx) ?

Comment: But that doesn't actually close the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
    processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);
    foreach (Process proc in processes)
    {
        if(proc.MainWindowTitle.equals(myTitle))
        {           
        proc.CloseMainWindow();
        proc.WaitForExit(); or use tempProc.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `GetProcessById()` is you already have a `Process`?

Comment: I have optained proccess first then iterated them to find the process  with respect to title bar text and then close that

Comment: But that doesn't explain what I'm asking. Why don't you simply call `proc.CloseMainWindow()` in the `if`?