# Closing multiple programs with the same name

Tags: vb.net, winforms, process

One part of my program is to close another program or the same program with the same name... I looked up how to do this and got this code:

```
Dim myprocesses() As Process
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  For Each p As Process In myprocesses
    If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("notepad") Then
      p.CloseMainWindow()
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

It should work, however when I run it I'm getting an error message on the `Next` statement saying:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Does anyone know what's wrong with the above code?

UPDATE: Some of these answers seem to work :) Thanks. However there is a slight problem because sometimes the program doesn't load up until about 30 seconds (notepad was just put there for simplicity) so I need the code to close the PROCESS and not the actual program when it loads.

Hope you can understand that xD ^^^^

Comment: You're not putting anything in `myProcesses()`; you're just declaring an empty array of `Process`. Do you expect it magically to fill itself somehow?

Comment: Are you wanting to close additional instances of your program while keeping the original still open ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you declared the `myprocesses()` but `null`, so to achieve your task you must use [`GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx)

```
For Each process1 As Object In Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")
    process1.Kill()
Next
```

But here's the **proper** way to manage the `.exe` [process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955853/1080742).

Comment: From the answer you linked, `Kill` is the proper way. You already mentioned it, so no point in linking to that answer. It may add confusion to OP. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in your button click event:

```
Dim myProc As System.Diagnostics.Process
For Each myProc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
  Console.WriteLine(myProc.MainWindowTitle)
  If myProc.MainWindowTitle.ToUpper.Contains("NOTEPAD") Then
    myProc.CloseMainWindow()
  End If
Next
```